# Gson Pojo class

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm making cryptocurrency information viewer now. I use Retrofit to get response, but have some problem.

https://api.coinone.co.kr/ticker/?currency=all

This is the api I use. and its structure is... too complicated to make pojo class.

if I make convert this to pojo class, then pojo class will be like

```
data class Coinone(
    val result: String,
    val errorCode: String,
    val timestamp: String,
    val crypto1: Ticker,
    val crypto2: Ticker,
    val crypto3: Ticker,
    
    ...

    val cryptoN: Ticker)
```

Should I do like that? Is that only one solution?

I mean, if api data would be updated, I must update my pojo class. If I don't, apps will surely make crushes.

Is there any solution for making pojo class with api having similar structure?

[image]

Gson Object used when I don't know about Retrofit, GsonConverter and Kotlin not so much.

Comment: It looks like that object is simply a map although those 3 `String` values are making it more problematic because they need to be excluded from the mapping process.

Comment: @Pawel it seems like the API is poorly constructed, all the crypto as it is could be inside an array and problem solved. @OverEasy could you create a Gon object and have `if is result key then string ... errorCode... timeStamp...` and `else parse it as Ticker`?

Comment: @cutiko
I'm remaking original apps using MVVM pattern, so have its gson object but... okay. I uploaded that object's picture in my post. Can you watch that?

Comment: `val gsonObject = Gson.fromString(theJson)` and then `gsonObject.forEachKey { key -> /*conditions to map it to something else/* }` does that pseudo code helps?

Comment: Did but fromString() is disappeared in Gson. 

Comment: I think... I find out. If I use body of 'Call<Any>', then maybe I can use that response as JSONObject.